# Insert data through Asp.net web API in sql server database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to insert data using web API.

I have taken empty web application with Web API folder and core references.

My AppModel Class

```
public class AppModel
{
    public int RegisterId { get; set; }
    public string RegisterName { get; set; }
    public string RegisterUserName { get; set; }
    public string RegisterPassword { get; set; }
    public string RegisterEmail { get; set; }
    public string RegisterMobile { get; set; }
    public DateTime RegisterDate { get; set; }
    public string RegisterStatus { get; set; }
}
```

Below is my HomeController code

```
public class HomeController : ApiController
{
    SqlConnection xc;
    SqlCommand xcmd;

    [HttpPost]
    public string RegisterUser([FromBody] AppModel register)
    {
        try
        {
            using (xc = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["db_appConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
            {
                xcmd = new SqlCommand("sp_insert_register", xc);
                xcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                xcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@register_id", register.RegisterId);
                xcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@register_name", register.RegisterName);
                xcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@register_username", register.RegisterUserName);
                xcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@register_password", register.RegisterPassword);
                xcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@register_email", register.RegisterEmail);
                xcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@register_mobile", register.RegisterMobile);
                xcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@register_date", DateTime.Now);
                xcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@register_status", "True");

                xc.Open();
                int i = xcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (i > 0)
                {
                    msg = "User Registered";
                }
                else
                {
                    msg = "Something went wrong.";
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            msg = ex.ToString();
        }
        return msg;
    }
}
```

I am confused how to pass values to these parameter.I am testing API in Postman.
I don't what key to pass in Body

Comment: What exactly your problem is ? If you want to pass parameters by postman, you can pass as a JSON array with all these parameters with KEY/VALUE pair.

Comment: Just pass a JSON object `{"RegisterId": "0", ...}`?

Comment: Just cross check data type of register_name in stored procedure if it is same or not

Comment: A couple of asides.  It is ill-advised to prefix a stored procedure with sp_.  There is a performance impact (see https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix for example).  Secondly, I always caution against AddWithValue as the DataType is inferred from the value.  This can have unforeseen consequences.  It is better to set the datatype yourself.

Comment: Thanks @GiorgiNakeuri. Actually I was passing parameters like this register.RegisterId

Comment: Thanks @DalvinderSingh for responding

Comment: Thanks @JonathanWillcock for advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Postman, Post your Json data as in the screen shot below:

Select the **Body** Tab, select **raw** and enter your json data.
On POST, your RegisterUser method will get the value in register variable which will be of type AppModel. 
ASP.NET WebAPI will manage this automatic conversion from Json to C# type.

[image]